# Perl regex extracting a match using braces

Tags: regex, perl, filepath

I tested the following code

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use English;

#this code extracts the current scripts filename 
#by removing the path from the filepath

my $Script_Name = $PROGRAM_NAME;

${Script_Name} =~ s/^.*\\//; #windows path

#${Script_Name} =~ s/^.*\///; #Unix based path

print $Script_Name;
```

and i don't understand why these braces extract the match without using a /r modifier. can anyone explain why and how this works or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a little confused!

The braces make no difference. `${Script_Name}` is identical to `$Script_Name`.

You code first copies the entire path to the script file from `$PROGRAM_NAME` to `$Script_Name`.

Then the substitution removes everything up to and including the last backslash, leaving just the file name.

The `/r` modifier would be used if you wanted to modify one string and put the result of the modification into another, so you could write your code in one step as

```
$Script_Name = $PROGRAM_NAME=~ s/^.*\\//r
```